# Rewrite rule for https://mysite.com/aboutus.page to https://mysite.com/adoutus.php to

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to apply a read write rule for converting Rewrite rule for  to https://mysite.com/aboutus.php to  https://mysite.com/aboutus.page, I have included the following in .htaccess file, but its not working.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you check `port 80` and that will not happen since you use `https`.

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^/?aboutus\.page$ https://mysite.com/about\.php [R,L]
```

Untested. Also since subject say one way, and quest text another way I don't know what you want.:)

Comment: Its redirecting to the same page, i want to the display of the URL to be "https://mysite.com/about.page".

Comment: `aboutus.php` to `about.page`?

Comment: yes, I want to the url to be about.page.

Comment: Updated my response. Should redirect `https` calls (not `http`) to aboutus.page to about.php.